# Elastic Search paginated search for more than 10,000 results

Tags: java, elasticsearch

As we know By default, we cannot use from and size to page through more than 10,000 hits. And as I discovered by conducting a Google search, if I use the search_after function, I can obtain results even after 10,000.

Here is the query

```
GET data/_search
{
  "from":0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "search_after":["trs"],
  "sort":[{"name" : "ASC"}]
}
```

I need to include it in my Java code, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

Here is the java code I need to modity

```
public SearchHits<Data> getAllData(ESListViewRequest request) {

    try {
        Query query = elasticSearchQueryBuilderImpl.build(request);
        if (query != null) {
            query.setPreference(DATA_PREFERENCE);
        }
        return operations.search(query, Data.class, IndexCoordinates.of(dataIndex));
    } catch (BuilderValidationException ex) {
        throw new ValidationException(ex.getErrorCode());
    }

}
```

As I am unfamiliar with elastic search, even a clue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this example using Java High Level. Remember select correctly field to [Sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html).

In the first request without searchAfter

```
//FIRST REQUEST
SearchSourceBuilder builder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
builder.sort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("metascore").order(SortOrder.DESC));
builder.size(2);
builder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.indices("idx_movies");
searchRequest.source(builder);
var response = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

System.out.println(response);
```

In the second request pass searchAfter and then get the paging.

```
//SECOND REQUEST WITH SEARCH AFTER
builder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
builder.sort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("metascore").order(SortOrder.DESC));
builder.size(2);
builder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());

searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.indices("idx_movies");
searchRequest.source(builder);

//USING SEARCH AFTER
Object[] arrSearchAfter = new Object[]{90};
builder.searchAfter(arrSearchAfter);

searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.indices("idx_movies3");
searchRequest.source(builder);
response = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: Your approach is right, however, my needs are slightly different. The page and size actually belong to the request itself. As a result, I'm in need of an elastic search query where if I provide the page and size it will give me the sort key by using which I can find search after data.

Comment: The search after works like this: you create your request (query) with sort from some field of your field. For each response document you will have access to sort data and will use some of them in the next request inside the search_after object. I recommend reading this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after).